# How to hide command line string on console when calling CreateProcess()?

Tags: windows

My program internally forks children processes to handle task for keeping possible crashes from the main process. When calling the `CreateProcess()` with command line `Worker.exe MyArg1 MyArg2`, this whole string show up on console. This internal process fork is not important, and I want to hide it from user.

The following is the how it is called.

```
wchar_t* wcsCommandLine[260] = L"Worker.exe MyArg1 MyArg2"
STARTUPINFO info = {};
info.cb = sizeof info;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
DWORD dwCreateFlags = 0;

BOOL bCreateProc = ::CreateProcessW(
     nullptr,              // lpApplicationName
     wcsCommandLine,
     0,                    // lpProcessAttributes
     0,                    // lpThreadAttributes
     TRUE,                 // bInheritHandles
     dwCreateFlags,
     0,                    // lpEnvironment
     0,                    // lpCurrentDirectory
     &info,
     &pi);
```

Trial 1 `dwCreateFlags`

I've tried add `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in `dwCreateFlags`. Although  the children prompt behave differently, it still shows the command line string.

Trial 2

I've added `system("@echo off")` before calling `CreateProcess()`, it does not work either.

Output

```
Progress: 0.23
Progress: 0.24
Worker.exe MyArg1 MyArg2      <-- Want to hide this

Progress: 0.25
Progress: 0.27
ProWorker.exe MyArg1 MyArg2   <-- Want to hide this
gress: 0.29
```

Comment: i don't thing here `c flag` apply. it seems `c++`

Comment: Sorry guys. This is a debug issue. It is so embarrassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateProcess` never prints anything to stdout nor stderr, there must be something else printing it, most likely a `printf` or `cout` call in your own code.